# How to use regular expressions in wget for rejecting files?

Tags: regex, linux, wget, download

I am trying to download the contents of a website using wget tool. I used -R option to reject some file types. but there are some other files which I don't want to download. These files are named as follows, and don't have any extensions.

```
string-ID
```

for example:

```
newsbrief-02
```

How I can tell wget not to download these files (the files which their names start with specified string)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can not specify a regular expression in the `wget -R` key, but you can specify a template (like file template in a shell).

The answer looks like:

```
$ wget -R 'newsbrief-*' ...
```

You can also use `?` and symbol classes `[]`.

For more information see [info wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options.html).

Comment: It may have been true at the date of the answer, but now You can use regular expressions to accept/reject patterns. See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21382873/4730881) below.

Comment: You can also reject multiple patterns at once with commas `wget -R 'newsbrief-*,string-*,*.txt'`

Answer (score 51):

Since (apparently) v1.14 `wget` accepts regular expressions : `--reject-regex` and `--accept-regex` (with `--regex-type posix` by default, can be set to `pcre` if compiled with `libpcre` support).

Beware that it seems you can use `--reject-regex` only once per `wget` call.  That is, you have to use `|` in a single regex if you want to select on several regex :

```
wget --reject-regex 'expr1|expr2|…' http://example.com
```

Comment: Does reject-regex work with things like `.` or `*`, what kind of regex is it, extended regex or PCRE regex?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai The second part of your question is already addressed in my answer.  It does work with `.` and `*`, e.g. `wget -r --reject-regex ".*foobar.*" http://example.com` will discard `http://example.com/foobar/`.

Comment: Note that it seems regex only works on recursive downloads, though.

Comment: I used it with `--spider`, and it I had to escape `[]`, so that means `[]` is also special. I only asked about what kind of regex it is because GNU grep also supports different kinds of regex, like extended regex and pcre regex.