# reject-regex in wget

Tags: wget

I'm trying to mirror a section of intranet TWiki for offline usage as follows:

```
wget \
--user=twiki \
--password=******** \
--recursive \
-l 2 \
--adjust-extension \
--page-requisites \
--convert-links \
--reject-regex '\?rev=' \
--reject-regex '/twiki/rdiff/' \
--reject-regex '/twiki/attach/' \
--reject-regex '/twiki/edit/' \
--reject-regex '/twiki/oops/' \
--reject-regex '\?raw=on' \
--reject-regex '\?cover=print' \
http://twiki/cgi-bin/twiki/view/SectionToMirror/
```

For some reason all --reject-regex are ignored. The content I want to reject appears in the copy. Running the above command without any --reject-regex rules renders the same results.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: from the man page `-reject-regex urlregex: Specify a regular expression to accept or reject the complete URL.` Maybe it would work if you surrounded your substrings with `.*` on both sides?

Comment: Do you mean:
`--reject-regex '.*/twiki/oops/.*' 
--reject-regex '.*\?raw=on.*' `
instead of:
`--reject-regex '/twiki/oops/'
--reject-regex '\?raw=on'`
?
I've tried that, made no difference.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. And I appear to be wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231736/how-to-use-regular-expressions-in-wget-for-rejecting-files

Comment: So actually the problem is that you can specify only one reject-regex and you have to stuff all the patterns into it separated by `|`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Multiple patterns have to be separated by a pipe symbol.