# How to use and 'OR' regular expression in --accept-regex in Wget

Tags: regex, download, wget

I want to recurse through select directories on a webpage where all it's sub-directories start with state abbreviations (e.g. CO_Boulder, CO_Denver, WY_Casper, WY_Cheyenne). In other words, I not interested in all 50 states, only three: CO, WY, and SD.

I have been able to filter with a single regular expression using --accept-regex but cannot figure out how to filter for two or more states. For example, I want to recurse only through directories starting with CO, WY, or SD.

`wget --accept-regex=^/CO_ --no-parent --recursive https://example.com/Projects/`

I tried the complement of an answer `wget --reject-regex 'expr1|expr2|…' http://example.com` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21382873/5610471 but the following did not work:

`wget --accept-regex '^/CO_|^/WY_' --no-parent --recursive https://example.com/Projects/`

Comment: Try: `^/(CO|WY|SD)_`

Comment: @Alireza, thanks. I keep getting the error: 'WY' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I tried --accept-regex '^/(CO|WY|SD)_'  and --accept-regex=^/(CO|WY|SD)_  and --accept-regex=^/(CO|WY|SD)_  and --accept-regex='^/(CO|WY|SD)_'